# Radio buttons - showing two diff list with data in the view WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button

I have some code in the view:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush8}">
        <RadioButton Content="Radio1" />
        <RadioButton Content="Radio2" />         
    </StackPanel>
    <ct:DynamicFilterPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                           ItemsType="{x:Type db:RadioData1}"
                           DbContext="{Binding DataContext}"
                           FilterQuery="{Binding FilterQuery, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           ChildCollectionsFilters="{Binding SubTypesFilter}"
                           WindowType="{x:Type mah:MetroWindow}"
                           />
    <ct:BDataGrid  Grid.Row="2" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Model.List}" SelectedItem="{Binding Model.SelectedItem}" />
```

And I have some class with data and name of columns, models and viewmodels.
When I start the app it shows columns with data of RadioData1. Ok. And the first radiobutton is for that. But how can I do when I click second radio button it shows another list with columns from RadioData2. What kind of converter? Or changes I have to make in this view.

Answer (score 0):

you must edit XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{StaticResource GrayBrush8}">
            <RadioButton Name="Radio1" Content="Radio1" DataContextChanged="RadioButton_DataContextChanged" />
            <RadioButton Name="Radio2" Content="Radio2" />
        </StackPanel>
```

and in CS File

add method

```
private void RadioButton_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Radio1.IsChecked==true)
            {
                //your Code
            }
            else
            {
                //your other code
            }
        }
```

and u can Use visibility for show or hide Something in XAML

```
<Button Name="btn1" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

and Use in your CS file like this

```
if (Radio1.IsChecked==true)
            {
                               btn1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
```

Comment: another question: can I through by radio buttons change the viewmodel <UserControl.DataContext>
        <mod:ViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext> Because of that depends the list in  <ct:BDataGrid >

Comment: Yes , I think you can use <UserControl.DataContext IsEnable=false>

and in Radio buttons can change False to True